# adjustOHLC error: incompatible array

Tags: r, quantmod

Please try to download "LOW" time series from yahoo and after use `adjustOHLC` function

```
library(quantmod)
data.env <- new.env()
getSymbols("LOW", src='yahoo', from='1970-01-01', env=data.env)
data.env[["LOW"]] <- adjustOHLC(data.env[["LOW"]], use.Adjusted=TRUE)
```

I receive an error: `` Error in `-.default`(Lo(x), Cl(x)) : non-conformable arrays ``. Can you help me to understand why?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a [known issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/24) with the `Lo` function on data for Lowe's stock ("LOW").

A simple work-around is to remove the "LOW." prefix from the column names.

```
colnames(data.env$LOW) <- gsub("^LOW\\.","",colnames(data.env$LOW))
data.env$LOW <- adjustOHLC(data.env$LOW, use.Adjusted=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Joshua Ulrich, ran into the same question, shouldn't this be debugged by the package developer?

Comment: @JasonGoal: It's a [known issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/24) without a simple solution. What do you mean by "debugged by the package developer"?  If you mean "fixed", it's hard to know the many possible use cases you may break by attempting to "fix" this one issue.  As a package developer, I don't like breaking people's working code...

Comment: I mean just add the simple solution into the `adjustOHLC` so nobody would run into this at the first place.